# One time reload window in angularjs on page load

Tags: angularjs

How can we reload window one time on page load I just try

```
$window.location.reload();
```

it looping all the times how can i set for once time when page load please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to reload on pageload?

Comment: my pages values are not loading properly

Comment: Maybe your problem it's not this question. Could you provide some code, to see what is your problem with the values loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put a flag and save it in localstorage and check the condition

```
if( localstorage.getItem("flag") == true ){    
    $window.location.reload();
    localstorage.setItem("flag", false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are re-loading your page on load time, whenever it loads the document, it gets the command to re-load the document, so your document re-loads.

You need to call you re-load command at button click or any other event except page load to avoid the cyclic reload.